# Where to best store frequently changed data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am creating a gaming service in which players will be paired and compete against one another in real-time. I am building this is node/websockets and react. My question is very high level:

Where should I store data like the number of users online, list of online users, etc. I am sure I can store it in a DB but I know it will change frequently. Is this best suited for one of nodes memory stores like "data-store" or just have a set of variables on the server accessible to the websockets (what I have now)?

Or should I just put it in a DB anyway???

Comment: you can store temporary data in session.

Comment: You can use Redis, an in memory database

Comment: Without knowing the flow and business logic of your app, nobody can give a really good recommendations. Voting close as too broad/ primarily opinion based

Comment: As long as the data you mentioned only needs to be available to one server, I would store it in memory. But if you want to expand your game and want different programs to access the data you should save it in some kind of datastore/database. Since your data structure would be relatively flat (I assume) and with few relations a Key-Value Store like the already mentioned Redis would be good, I think.

Your question still very broad, maybe elaborate a bit more.

Comment: The data you mention does not need to persist when the server goes down.  So, for a single server, just keep the data in memory in your server.  For a cluster of servers, use a memory based database like redis that all servers can access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have a single server and the data is all of the type you've listed that is temporal (doesn't need to survive a server restart), then just using a set of variables and keeping the data in memory is perfectly fine, is simplest to implement and will perform the best.  There is really no reason to involve the additional overhead of a traditional disk-based store unless the data is overly large (which it does not seem to be).

If you cluster your server, then frequently changed data that does not need to be persistently stored across server restarts can be kept in an in-memory database in it's own process such as redis.  Each server in your cluster can then query redis any time it needs the latest copy of the data.  Because it's an in-memory data store, it's efficient for data that changes a lot while also being available to multiple processes.

Comment: This answer was very helpful. I am planning to eventually run multiple docker instances and will look more into Redis at that point. But for now this answer 100% cleared up my concerns. :)